# How to make hyperlinks work in Chrome packaged app?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a packaged app with multiple pages. When I click on a button in my homepage, it does not open the link. Is there any way to open hyperlinks in the same frame for Google Chrome packaged apps?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript to manage your links and disable it's default behavior.

Something like this ( if you use jQuery or similar ):

```
$("a").live("click keydown", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get( $(this).attr("href") )
        .success(function(data, status, ajax){
             $('body').empty().replaceWith( $(data).find('body') );
        })
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you have any code written in javascript? I dont really know anything about jQuery.

Comment: This code is from my website and chrome application. More info about jQuery you can find on it website: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, I'm new to jQuery too.